# Training VGG16 with CIFAR-10 dataset in TensorFlow, can't get good accuracy

Tags: tensorflow

I am a beginner to study ML. I am studying the VGG16 model in TensorFlow. My study is [here](https://github.com/NienfengYao/TensorFlow_Study).

Now I meet a question and still can't find the reason. I studied the two case.

1. Study pre-trained VGG16-A model to do predict. ([VGG in TensorFlow](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~frossard/post/vgg16/))
2. Study VGG16-B model with CIFAR-10 dataset to do training. ([Ashing00/Tensorflow_VGG](https://github.com/Ashing00/Tensorflow_VGG))

They all work fine. But now I want to simulate the Case 2.'s procedure, try to use VGG16-A model to do training with CIFAR-10 dataset. But I am failed, I can't get good accuracy.

The testing is in [vgg16f_training_cifar10.ipynb](https://github.com/NienfengYao/TensorFlow_Study/blob/master/vgg16/vgg16_final/vgg16f_training_cifar10.ipynb). Can someone give me some hint?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I add batch normalization in each hidden layer. Now we can get good accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add batch normalization in each hidden layer. Now we can get good accuracy.